# What hardware and bandwidth requirements would a server need to fulfill to run Bitcore?

Tags: api, bitpay, bitcore

What's the cost of running Bitcore on AWS or DigitalOcean? I know I'd need about 128gb of hardrive space, but I'm not sure how much the typical bandwidth costs would be, and how much RAM or cores I would need.

My goal is to create an API for looking up balances. Thanks for any advice!

Comment: Cost in purely monetary terms? Or in terms of processing power? Or wattage??

Comment: I'm looking for how much monetary cost it would be

Comment: fire one up and let us know, you should probably test on a virtual machine and lookup rates on the service providers website based on what you found in your test environment!
http://calculator.s3.amazonaws.com/index.html